# How to add target link libraries .so and .a file in CmakeList?

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I create a cmake txt file in that i add target link libraries to link.
Cmake look like this..

```
    file(GLOB libs ${ANDROID_LIBS}/*.so) 
    file(GLOB libs_user ${ANDROID_LIBS}/*.a)
    add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE} ${SOURCE_JAVA} ${HEADERS} )
    target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} ${libs} ${libs_user})
```

I have Android libs folder in that i have all .so and .a files.
Cmake successfully builded and created .so file. But when i was testing i have an error  A/libc(18333): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x01010000 (code=1)

Then i change Cmakelist code to

```
file(GLOB libs ${ANDROID_LIBS}/libopencv_java.so ${ANDROID_LIBS}/libcaffe.so)
  file(GLOB libs_user ${ANDROID_LIBS}/*.a)
  add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE} ${SOURCE_JAVA} ${HEADERS} )
  target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} ${libs} ${libs_user})
```

This become successfull.

whats my question is whats wrong linking target libraries cannot be linked(*.so). When i hardcode .so file its becomes runnable. Please justify..

Comment: What is content of `libs` variable in both cases? (You can output it via `message()` command.)

Answer (score 0):

Conflicting symbols?
[how to link with two shared libraries with many conflicting functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680481/how-to-link-with-two-shared-libraries-with-many-conflicting-functions)

I am not sure if that has to do with android related stuff...